# Trouble initializing firestore functions in flultter

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to add firestore functions to my flutter project. Unfortunately, I seem to be having a lot of issues. If I use npm v13.7.0, the latest version, and run the function "firebase init functions" from the root of my project, I get the error

```
Error: Server Error. certificate has expired
```

I've tried updating firebase tools logging in and out of firebase in the command line, but none of this helps.

If I use npm version 10.6, I get the message

```
Firebase initialization complete!
```

However, it doesn't look like anything has actually been done - no "functions" folder has been created, and I can't find a firestore.json file associated with the project. It also gives me several messages like `'File functions/.eslintrc.json already exists. Overwrite?`, however I can't find any such file.

Has anyone else run into these issues/has an idea of what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had actually initialized a firebase project in the folder above the folder I was working in, and whenever I called `firebase init functions` the functions folder was getting created in this higher level folder. I deleted the firebase.json file in the upper level directory, switched back to my directory of interest, and called `firebase init functions` again (using npm version 10.6), and then it worked.